# how to merge two array, and then short the resultant array as merged array values comes first irrelative to key values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

$community gets all the communities.
$starred communities gets all the starred communities.
And then both of them are merged.

**Here is code:**

```
$communities = Community::all();
$starred_communities = StarredCommunity::where('user_id',1)->get();
$communities = $communities->merge($starred_communities);
```

I want resultant array should get $starred_communities at starting positions. Presently result is being shorted according to the primary keys of both records.

Comment: Whats happens when you merge them this way?

Comment: it shorts the result according to primarry keys

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you edit your question with the desired sample $communities output and what you are getting now?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by shorted array. Can you give a real example that you are getting?

Comment: You mean you want an array where the first entries are starred communities and then the normal communities? Like this `[starred, starred, normal, normal...]`

Comment: yess......you are right

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$communities = Community::all();
$starred_communities = StarredCommunity::where('user_id',1)->get();

$merged = $communities->toBase()->merge($starred_communities);
```

The `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` class uses the the `key` of the Eloquent model (`id` by default) as index, whereas the `Illuminate\Support\Collection` does not care about this.

Comment: Sorry looks like I had the variables flipped. I updated the example

Answer (score 0):

Try should work:

```
$communities = Community::get();
$starred_communities = StarredCommunity::where('user_id',1)->get();

$merged = $starred_communities->merge($communities);
```